# Date comparison failure

Tags: java, validation, datetime

I wrote an annotation to check if a date is in the future and this is the ivValid implementation:

```
public boolean isValid( Date date, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext )
    {
        String message = null;

        Date todayWithoutTime = DateUtils.truncate( Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );

        if ( ( date == null ) || ( !date.after( todayWithoutTime ) && !date.equals( todayWithoutTime ) ) )
        {
            message = "{validation.definition.notfutureDate}";
        }

        if ( message != null )
        {
            constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( message ).addConstraintViolation();
        }

        return message == null;
    }
```

I have the following date objects:

```
date    Timestamp  (id=157) 
    cdate   Gregorian$Date  (id=192)    
        cachedFixedDateJan1 734869  
        cachedFixedDateNextJan1 735234  
        cachedYear  2013    
        daylightSaving  3600000 
        dayOfMonth  30  
        dayOfWeek   3   
        era null    
        forceStandardTime   false   
        fraction    0   
        hours   0   
        leapYear    false   
        locale  null    
        millis  0   
        minutes 0   
        month   4   
        normalized  true    
        seconds 0   
        year    2013    
        zoneinfo    ZoneInfo  (id=212)  
        zoneOffset  7200000 
    fastTime    1367272800000   
    nanos   0
```

and

```
todayWithoutTime    Date  (id=173)  
    cdate   Gregorian$Date  (id=185)    
        cachedFixedDateJan1 734869  
        cachedFixedDateNextJan1 735234  
        cachedYear  2013    
        daylightSaving  3600000 
        dayOfMonth  30  
        dayOfWeek   3   
        era null    
        forceStandardTime   false   
        fraction    0   
        hours   0   
        leapYear    false   
        locale  null    
        millis  0   
        minutes 0   
        month   4   
        normalized  true    
        seconds 0   
        year    2013    
        zoneinfo    ZoneInfo  (id=212)  
        zoneOffset  7200000 
    fastTime    1367272800000
```

date.getTime() gives 13672728000000 and todayWithoutTime.getTime() gives 13672728000000.

Can someone please explain me why the check **!date.equals( todayWithoutTime )** returns true??

Comment: You work with dates? Use JodaTime.

Comment: Are you sure `!date.equals( todayWithoutTime )` returns `true`? (*two Date objects are equal if and only if the getTime method returns the same long value for both*)..

Comment: Looks like you have a mistake in your debug manual process. Add the printouts of these date objects `.getTime()` before their comparison in your code to be sure, that they are really equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `date` variable is actually a `Timestamp`. From [`Timestamp` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

> The Timestamp.equals(Object) method never returns true when passed a
>   value of type java.util.Date because the nanos component of a date is
>   unknown.

The javadoc also recommends not using `Timestamp` where `Date` is expected, even if `Timestamp` inherits from `Date`.

Comment: Ahhh. I didn't noticed... Thank you.

Comment: Liskov Substitution Principle ... My @*s